# customize list module in orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I want to have my custom lists module in my orchard project

for that: I copied all schema(include handler, controller , views, ...) from 
default Orchard.Lists module to MyList Module.


when I run MyList module, and I click the Contained Items() link in UI, this exception crashed in a view with name: "Parts.Container.BulkActions.cshtml :


Cannot convert type 'Mypro.MyLists.ViewModels.ContentOptions' to 'Orchard.Lists.ViewModels.ContentOptions'

I know what's mean:

but , I changed all namespace and area name in Routes file. I don't know why my module redirects to the view(Parts.Container.BulkActions.cshtml) that belong to defualt orchard.lists module? instead of redirect to the view in my module?

Comment: I found it! Orchard keeps the Name and source of views using  the BindingsName and BindingSource property in  ShapeBinding class. now, how Can I change the BindingSource of my BindingsName('BulkActions.cshtml') ? where store the list of ShapeBindings? for that I edit it.

Comment: What are yountrying to do that justifies copy-pasting a whole module?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: Hi Bertrand. I was hope that you see my question!. because of I going to use all features of Orchard.Lists . and also customize the Lists for myself...?

Comment: Right. Why would you need to copy the module in order to do that?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: because of I created another module ('MyProj.List') that copied from orchar.lists.

Comment: yes. My question is why did you do that? It's bad practice and untirely unnecessary.